# How do you migrate from a list to a class C# DataContract Serialization?

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

How can I migrate a configuration to a new class from a list of bools? Previously it used a list of bool, but the list was being abused as a class, with each index having a specific meaning like a field.

I want to migrate it from a List, to a class that instead acts as the list for serialization purposes, but exposes normal fields to the rest of the application.

How can I write class ListEmulator so that it serializes out to a list, without introducing new xml tags?

old code

```
namespace
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Configuration
    {
        public const string FileName = "Configuration.xml";

        public Configuration()
        {
            AList = new List<bool>();
            AGuidList = new List<Guid>();
        }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Guid> AGuidList { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public List<bool> AList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

new code.

```
namespace
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Configuration
    {
        public const string FileName = "Configuration.xml";

        public Configuration()
        {
            AListEmulator = new ListEmulator();
            AGuidList = new List<Guid>();
        }

        [DataMember]
        public List<Guid> AGuidList { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public ListEmulator AListEmulator { get; set; }
    }
}

public class ListEmulator
{

    public ListEmulator()
    {
        new ListEmulator(true, true, true, true);
    }

    public ListEmulator(bool item0, bool item1, bool item2, bool item3)
    {
        this.IsPlanned = item0;
        this.IsCompleted = item1;
        this.IsRemaining = item2;
        this.IsSerial = item3;
    }

    public bool IsPlanned { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsRemaining { get; set; }
    public bool IsSerial { get; set; }
}
```

The reason a list is needed, is there is old migration code that needs to be ported for when there was only 1 element, then 2, 3, 4 with different defaults for each.  If it weren't for the fact that I have existing deployed configuration files in the original format, it would probably be time for them to all be named in the XML individually.  However, I need to retain the current format for now.  For the sake of migration I'm wondering how I can accomplish the above.

Comment: You mean, you want your XML to continue to have an array of `bool` values, or you want your XML to change to actually show meaningful element names like `<IsPlanned>true</IsPlanned>`, and be upgraded correctly when read? At the beginning of the question you write you want to do this *without introducing new xml tags*, but then latter write *it's probably time they were all named in the xml individually*.  Which do you want?

Comment: The first. Mainly for educational reasons. Knowing how to read the first, but write the second, as well as reading the second would be nice though.

Comment: Actually the second is easier in my opinion, but I'll see if I can answer the first.

Comment: Reason being is I have existing deployed configuration files in the first original format, if you want to know the motivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One option** would be for your `ListEmulator` to inherit from [`Collection<bool>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx), and then add specific named properties to access elements in the array, like so:

```
public class ListEmulator : Collection<bool>
{
    const bool IsPlannedDefault = false;  // Change to the appropriate values.
    const bool IsCompletedDefault = false;
    const bool IsRemainingDefault = false;
    const bool IsSerialDefault = false;

    void AddAllDefaults()
    {
        // Customize the code here to upgrade old collections with fewer than 4 elements to the current 4-element format.
        if (Count < 1)
            Add(IsPlannedDefault);
        if (Count < 2)
            Add(IsCompletedDefault);
        if (Count < 3)
            Add(IsRemainingDefault);
        if (Count < 4)
            Add(IsSerialDefault);
    }

    public ListEmulator() { }

    public ListEmulator(bool item0, bool item1, bool item2, bool item3)
    {
        this.IsPlanned = item0;
        this.IsCompleted = item1;
        this.IsRemaining = item2;
        this.IsSerial = item3;
    }

    public bool IsPlanned { get { return this.ElementAtOrDefault(0, IsPlannedDefault); } set { AddAllDefaults(); this[0] = value; } }
    public bool IsCompleted { get { return this.ElementAtOrDefault(1, IsCompletedDefault); } set { AddAllDefaults(); this[1] = value; } }
    public bool IsRemaining { get { return this.ElementAtOrDefault(2, IsRemainingDefault); } set { AddAllDefaults(); this[2] = value; } }
    public bool IsSerial { get { return this.ElementAtOrDefault(3, IsSerialDefault); } set { AddAllDefaults(); this[3] = value; } }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, bool item)
    {
        if (index > 3)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index > 3");
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Then in your `Configuration` simply replace `List<bool>` with `ListEmulator`, keeping the old element name:

```
    [DataMember]
    public ListEmulator AList { get; set; }
```

Because this type implements `IEnumerable<T>`, the `DataContractSerializer` will serialize it as a collection rather than as an object with properties.  (You might want to change the class name since it's really not a list *emulator* at this point.)  However, *this only works if you do not add any initial values to the collection from within the default constructor.*

**Another option** would be to add a surrogate property to `Configuration` that handles the necessary conversions, and mark the `ListEmulator AList` as not serialized:

```
[DataContract]
public class Configuration
{
    public const string FileName = "Configuration.xml";

    public Configuration()
    {
        AList = new ListEmulator();
        AGuidList = new List<Guid>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<Guid> AGuidList { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "AList")]
    bool[] AlistArray
    {
        get
        {
            return AList == null ? null : AList.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            AList = new ListEmulator(value);
        }
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember] // Do not serialize this property directly
    public ListEmulator AList { get; set; }
}

public class ListEmulator
{
    const bool IsPlannedDefault = false;  // Change to the appropriate values.
    const bool IsCompletedDefault = false;
    const bool IsRemainingDefault = false;
    const bool IsSerialDefault = false;

    public ListEmulator(IList<bool> list)
    {
        IsPlanned = list.ElementAtOrDefault(0, IsPlannedDefault);
        IsCompleted = list.ElementAtOrDefault(1, IsCompletedDefault);
        IsRemaining = list.ElementAtOrDefault(2, IsRemainingDefault);
        IsSerial = list.ElementAtOrDefault(3, IsSerialDefault);
    }

    public ListEmulator()
    {
        new ListEmulator(true, true, true, true);
    }

    public ListEmulator(bool item0, bool item1, bool item2, bool item3)
    {
        this.IsPlanned = item0;
        this.IsCompleted = item1;
        this.IsRemaining = item2;
        this.IsSerial = item3;
    }

    public bool IsPlanned { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsRemaining { get; set; }
    public bool IsSerial { get; set; }

    public bool[] ToArray()
    {
        return new[] { IsPlanned, IsCompleted, IsRemaining, IsSerial };
    }
}
```

Both options use the following extension method:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static T ElementAtOrDefault<T>(this IList<T> list, int index, T defaultValue)
    {
        if (index < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(string.Format("index = {0}", index));
        if (list == null || index >= list.Count)
            return defaultValue;
        return list[index];
    }
}
```